# Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKBasicUtility

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, fbsdk

I use something called Gamemaker and have an extension that adds basic Facebook functionality, analytics, login etc.

I've also got another extension that ads ironSource ads, which includes facebook ads.  I can get the app to build in XCode if I use just one or the other, but can not for the life of me get this to work with both included.

I have attached an image of the full error.

Any help would be hugely thanked.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwbRQ.jpg)

Comment: In general with this error just make sure you have the framework that the error is pointing to.  In this case FBSDKCoreKit as answered below.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

1. Go to your Project
2. Select your Target
3. Then, go to Build Phases
4. Open Link Binary With Libraries
5. Add + ‘FBSDKCoreKit’ framework.

This should solve the issue